# GHC type error which I do not understand

Tags: haskell, ghc

I am teaching myself Haskell.

I want to write a function that recursively finds the first number that has an integer square root and is smaller than a starting number.

It looks like this:

```
findFirstSquare :: Int -> Int
findFirstSquare x
    | x <= 0                                  = error "This function only works for 1 or above"
    | fromInteger(floor(sqrt(x))) == (sqrt x) = x
    | otherwise                               = intSqrt(x - 1)
```

But GHC complains:

> No instance for (RealFrac Int) arising from a use of `floor' at ...

However, if I type the following into GHCi, it happily compiles it:

```
 fromInteger(floor(sqrt(4))) == (sqrt 4)
```

My question is: Why am I getting a type error from an expression that compiles successfully in GHCi?

Comment: it's actually a type error, not a parse error, right?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out.

The difference is that the constant "4" is overloaded, so interactively sqrt(4) is getting the square root of the **Float** 4

However my function declares x as an **Int**, therefore I needed to add a fromIntegral to the calls to sqrt, so that they would work.

Changing the middle guard to the following did the trick:

```
| fromIntegral(floor(sqrt(fromIntegral(x)))) == (sqrt(fromIntegral(x))) = x
```

Comment: That's right. Except I'd use `fromInteger` in place of `fromIntegral`.

Comment: Incidentally, `fromInteger` is also used by GHCi to do the "overloading" of numeric literals.

Comment: @Alexey Why would you use `fromInteger` instead of `fromIntegral`? `fromInteger` is a useless function; all its uses are covered by `fromIntegral`