# Understanding type-related Haskell errors when using sqrt

Tags: haskell, types, typeclass, type-constraints

I've been reading [Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com) for a few days (chaps 1-6) and there are several things, even in the land of newbies, which are not clear to me.

For instance, I've been trying to implement a script to solve [this classic problem](https://projecteuler.net/problem=3) of finding the largest prime factor of an integer.

I'm pretty sure my approach,

- check if the number is a square and return its square root if so,
- otherwise search for divisors downward from its square root, scanning only odd numbers,

<s>is probably not the right one,</s> **is plainly wrong**, as pointed out in the answer and the comments (I hope I would have realized this myself, if I had been able to write a compilable code), but at least it's being a chance to practice Haskell's syntax and not only.

The only commented line is the one with which I'm having issue. What is "strange" to me, is that the errors are about the two lines just after that, whereas everything works fine if I change the lamda to something which does not use both `x` and `e` (except that the result is wrong, clearly).

```
largestprime x
  | isSquare = srx
  | otherwise = head $ filter (\e -> x `mod` e == 0) lst --Lambda
    where intsqrt = floor . sqrt
          isSquare = sqrt x == fromInteger(intsqrt x)
          srx = intsqrt x
          lst = [i,i-2..]
            where i = if odd srx then srx else srx - 1
```

My understanding is that something is wrong with the types that are deduced for `e` and `x`, however the error is not very helpful, given my current level:

```
Main.hs:59:21: error:
    • No instance for (RealFrac Integer) arising from a use of ‘floor’
    • In the first argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘floor’
      In the expression: floor . sqrt
      In an equation for ‘intsqrt’: intsqrt = floor . sqrt
   |
59 |     where intsqrt = floor . sqrt
   |                     ^^^^^

Main.hs:59:29: error:
    • No instance for (Floating Integer) arising from a use of ‘sqrt’
    • In the second argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘sqrt’
      In the expression: floor . sqrt
      In an equation for ‘intsqrt’: intsqrt = floor . sqrt
   |
59 |     where intsqrt = floor . sqrt
   |                             ^^^^

Main.hs:60:22: error:
    • No instance for (Floating Integer) arising from a use of ‘sqrt’
    • In the first argument of ‘(==)’, namely ‘sqrt x’
      In the expression: sqrt x == fromInteger (intsqrt x)
      In an equation for ‘isSquare’:
          isSquare = sqrt x == fromInteger (intsqrt x)
   |
60 |           isSquare = sqrt x == fromInteger(intsqrt x)
   |                      ^^^^^^
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

Concerning `e`, it is an element of `lst`, which is a list whose elements are of the same type as `srx`, which is the type in output from `floor`, which based on `:t floor` seems to be `Integral`. So maybe I just have to define the type of `largestprime` appropriately?

I've seen some questions exist already on the topic, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1304521/5825294) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18547341/haskell-sqrt-type-error). However I'm a bit confused at the moment.

Besides receiving help so that I can solve the problem, it'd be also nice to receive some advices on how to read those errors, which at the moment are close to arabic for me.

Comment: Put type signatures on all your variables. The error messages will become much more helpful.

Comment: it's better if there is just one, focused question per question.

Comment: @WillNess, are you referring to me asking side question in the comments?

Comment: I'm referring to the question itself. when a question is focused on one specific thing it is much easier to write - and then read and interpret - an answer. it is OK to post multiple different questions about the same piece of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few places where you seem to be a little confused in whether you are using an `Integral` type or a `RealFrac` one. A good technique to make sure you don't confuse yourself is to use type annotations.

To start off, what is the input and output of the function you are creating, `largestprime`? IMO, it should be integral types on both ends, since it doesn't make sense to talk about prime factors if you have non-integers.

```hs
largestprime :: Integral a => a -> a
```

So, then we want to find the square root of the input. Unfortunately, `sqrt` doesn't belong to `Integral`, but to `Floating` (just run `:i sqrt` in GHCi). What we can do instead is use the `fromIntegral` function, which has the following type signature:

```hs
fromIntegral :: (Integral a, Num b) => a -> b
```

So in order to find the square root of our integer, we have to use `sqrt . fromIntegral`. To check if the number is a square, we can do

```
isSquare = let y = fromIntegral x in sqrt y == fromIntegral (floor $ sqrt y)
```

or

```
isSquare = let y = fromIntegral x in ceiling (sqrt y) == floor (sqrt y)
```

So far, we've got the "is a perfect square" case figured out and working. Next up is the rest.

The list of candidates for us to check for divisibility is `[i, i-2 ..]` for `i` being as you've defined. So, following your code, we first filter for those that divide `x`:

```hs
filter (\n -> x `mod` n == 0) [i, i-2, ..]
```

We want the first number that matches our criteria (that is, wasn't filtered). So, just as you did, we take the `head`:

```hs
head $ filter (\n -> x `mod` n == 0) [i, i-2, ..]
```

The whole function is:

```hs
largestprime :: Integral a => a -> a
largestprime x  | isSquare  = root
                | otherwise = head $ filter (\n -> x `mod` n == 0) [i, i-2 ..]
    where   isSquare = let y = fromIntegral x in ceiling (sqrt y) == floor (sqrt y)
            root     = floor $ sqrt $ fromIntegral x
            i        = if odd root then root else root - 1
```

And now we've got a function that compiles successfully. I didn't really cover this in this answer, but a tip to solving GHC errors is to go from the bottom — always fix the last error first. In your case, you would've seen right off that `sqrt x` complains that `x` isn't a `Floating` type.

I just think it's also worth quickly mentioning that your algorithm does not do what you think it does. Sure, it will return one of its factors, but it's not necessarily prime (`largestprime 36` gives `6`, which isn't prime).

Comment: Concerning your suggestion on reading comments, the last error is `No instance for (Floating Integer) arising from a use of ‘sqrt’`; what does this mean? That the interpreter expected `x` to be both `Floating` and `Integer`?

Comment: Also, what makes the code compile if the lambda does not use both `x` and `e` in my attempt? I'm thinking to something possibly nonsensical like `(\e -> e > 0)`. Why with such a lamda the error is not triggered?

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis `No instance for (Floating Integer) [...]` means that the _type_ `Integer` isn't in the _typeclass_ `Floating`. It uses this notation because instance declarations in Haskell follow the syntax `instance TypeClass Type`.

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis As for your second question, the problem arises when using both because (in your code) `x` is a `Floating` type and `e` is an `Integral` type. If you look for the type of `mod`, you'll see that both of its operands must be of the same type, which is not happening (`Floating` and `Integral` are meant to be exclusive, as far as I know)

Answer (score 1):

Having defined your function, check its type right away:

```
> :t largestprime
largestprime :: (RealFrac c, Integral c, Floating c) => c -> c
```

Here's the problem right there: its type demands an input value's type to be an `Integral` and also a `Floating` and `RealFrac` type at the same time.

Why? Because the same `x` is used as input to `mod` and `sqrt` (and, inside `intsqrt`, to `floor`):

```
> :t mod
mod   ::  Integral a              => a -> a -> a

> :t sqrt
sqrt  ::  Floating a              => a -> a

> :t floor
floor :: (RealFrac a, Integral b) =>      a -> b

> :t floor . sqrt
floor . sqrt :: (RealFrac a, 
          Integral b, Floating a) => a ->      b
```

Why did it compile? Because theoretically you could define - in some other module - a type which is an instance of all the typeclasses in the constraint, and use this function with it.

The errors `No instance for (RealFrac Integer)` and `No instance for (Floating Integer)` just mean that you haven't done so (your `Integral` has defaulted to `Integer`).

Comment: What specific "incarnation" of the script are you referring to in your first chunk of code?

Comment: I have no chunks of code in my answer. I loaded your definition of `largestprime x ... = ...` (the only one there is in your question), and then issued a `:t` command at GHCi's prompt, then copy-pasted the command and the response.

Comment: But that gives an error which ends with `Failed, no modules loaded`, how could you then run `:t largestprimve` successfully? (I'm sorry, by _chunck of code_ I meant _chunk of code-formatted text_.)

Comment: [here](https://repl.it/repls/DearestLeftQueryplan) I had to make one small change to make it compile, changing `fromInteger` to `fromIntegral`.

Comment: [another](https://repl.it/repls/GeneralLoathsomeLint) way to make it work without any changes to the code, is with the NoMonomorphismRestriction pragma (this means you have the Monomorphism Restriction enabled on your installation; the pragma removes the restriction) . then `:t largestprime` shows that same type, even in the repl.it window.